# Google token endpoint returning unsupported grant type

Tags: node.js, axios, google-oauth, openid-connect, google-openid

I'm trying to implement Google Oauth to get information on users who sign in with Google such as their name and profile photo.

I found [this react library](https://github.com/MomenSherif/react-oauth/) which seems like it can get me a `code` when using the [`flow: 'auth_code'` param](https://github.com/MomenSherif/react-oauth/#authorization-code-flow).

Additionally I've found [these Google docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect#exchangecode) which outline how to exchange a `code` for an ID token which will have [user information](https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect#an-id-tokens-payload).

I can successfully retrieve a code using the react component as shown in this slightly redacted log message from my browser:

```
{
    "code": "4/0AWtgzh4VK3QT85egP0m9Rsau_gND-FPDxpM-cPB7ocxTfNkZSCzFSbE86<redacted suffix>",
    "scope": "email profile openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "authuser": "0",
    "prompt": "consent"
}
```

I then send this code to my backend which fires off the following request to the token endpoint as found in the [Discovery document](https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration), mentioned in the [OpenID Google docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect#exchangecode):

```
    try {
      const resp = await axios.post("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", {
        code: googleJWT,
        client_id: getGoogleClientId(),
        client_secret: googleSecret,
        redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000",
        grant_type: "authorization_code"
      }, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
      })
      console.log("################## posted", resp)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("################## could not post")
      console.log(e)
    }
```

However, this results in an error being thrown:

```
      error: 'unsupported_grant_type',
      error_description: 'Invalid grant_type: '
```

even though a grant type of `authorization_code` is reported as supported by the [Discovery document](https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration).

For completeness, here's the redacted axios config that gets printed with the above error message:

```
 config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.26.1',
      'Content-Length': 298
    },
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
    data: '{"code":"4/0AWtgzh4VK3QT85egP0m9Rsau_gND-FPDxpM-cPB7ocxTfNkZSCzFSbE86<redacted>","client_id":"221274282648-q9nrm8j61s5cba218qot926vnloua2hb.apps.googleusercontent.com","client_secret":"<redacted>","redirect_uri":"http://localhost:3000","grant_type":"authorization_code"}'
  },
```

Why is google complaining that the provided grant type isn't supported and how can I swap this code for an ID token?